# Counting bases in a sequence - Nonetype

Tags: python, count, dna-sequence

I am trying to create a function where the user is able to input a file name (containing a DNA sequence), and the respective number of bases present in the selected file are counted and output onto the screen in the order: #A, #G, #C, #T. I then want to save that output as a new file under a user input name with extension .count. In bash I am then trying to concatenate those file (will be 100 in total) into a single .csv document with the following format:

| File | #A,#G,#C,#T |
| --- | --- |
| file.count 1 | 23,43,32,41 |
| file.count 2 | etc... |

```
To open the file, I have:

def openseq(filename):
  filename=input("enter file to open: ")
  openfile=open(filename,"r")
  dnatext=print(openfile.read())
  return dnatext
```

and then originally I was trying to next a for loop within (under dnatext) with the following:

```
for i in dnatext:
    comma = ","
    numberofbases=str(dnatext.count('A')) + comma + str(dnatext.count('G'))   + comma + str(dnatext.count('C')) + comma + str(dnatext.count('T'))
  return numberofbases
```

And then to save the file under a new name input by the user:

```
directory="<desired directory>" #removed directory for privacy
  newname= input("Enter output file name: ")
  filepath = directory + newname + ".count"
  filepath.close()
```

But no matter how i move things around i either get the error message TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable or that some variable is not defined. I've tried a few ways to try and resolve this but am just not having any luck and seeing as i am relatively new to coding (especially combination of python and bash) i would very much appreciate some help or even an explanation as to why I am unable to count the number of bases in the inputed sequence.

Ideally I am trying to get this all into 1 or 2 functions so I can call them easily in bash but I am not sure whether that is even possible.

Comment: The `print` function returns nothing.  Do the `read` and the `print` in separate lines.  Next, since you have the whole text in one big block, you do NOT want to do `for i in dnatext:`, which will loop character by character.  Just do the `count` calls without the loop.

Comment: You can use "split" rather than "for" loop, its more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but in general, "NoneType is not iterable" means (perhaps unsurprisingly) that you're trying to iterate over the value `None`.

In your code you posted there's only one place where you iterate:

```
for i in dnatext:
```

Here `dnatext` is expected to be iterable and your error suggests it's in fact `None`.

The cause is probably the bug in this function:

```
def openseq(filename):
    filename=input("enter file to open: ")
    openfile=open(filename,"r")
    dnatext=print(openfile.read())  # <-- this line
    return dnatext
```

The `print` function doesn't return anything (or returns `None`, depending on how you look at it).  So this function will always return `None`.

Instead, you *probably* (but again, it's hard to say) want:

```
def openseq(filename):
    filename = input("enter file to open: ")
    with open(filename,"r") as openfile:
        dnatext = openfile.read()
    print(dnatext)
    return dnatext
```

which

- uses a context manager to also close the file handle for you, and
- prints *and returns* the data that was read (instead of just printing it)

Comment: Hi @jedwards thank you! I am not confident that I even need the print(dnatext) line but now my issue is counting the bases as apparently 'dnatext' is not assigned as an actual variable containing the sequence data. I believe once I am able to assign the sequence to a variable I should be able to count the bases no problem